# How to set custom price for a product in Magento for only the first of that product added to the cart?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I trying to allow users to get the first product sample they add to their cart for free, but any samples they add after (including the one they already added) should be normal price. Right now I using **setOriginalCustomPrice** in a module, but the customer can change the quantity, and the price stays at zero instead of going up. Anyone know how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by a simple calculation where you are using setOriginalCustomPrice.Currently I think you are setting price 0.Instead of doing this,use following logic to set custom price.

```
 $customPrice=$qtyincart*$productPrice-$productPrice.
```

So if user add 1 qty then $customPrice will be 0 else will equal to sum of qty-1.

I hope this solve your purpose.